# How to populate flex combo box with xml data

Tags: apache-flex

here is the xml data :

```
<root>
    <recommendedMaterials>
        <value label="Aluminium" data="0" /> 
        <value label="Iron" data="0" /> 
    </recommendedMaterials>

</root
```

My code :

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
public function populateRecommendedMaterials(xml_val:XML)           
            {
                 materials_Cmb.dataProvider=(xml_val.recommendedMaterials); 
            }

    ]]>

</mx:Script>        

    <mx:ComboBox x="212" y="164" id="materials_Cmb" dataProvider="materialsCmb_Dp"></mx:ComboBox>

</mx:Canvas>
```

The problem is that the whole xml gets populated. I just want the labels. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches here, depending on what you need. In either case the data you want are the *children* of the `recommendedMaterials` node, not the node itself (which is what you did).

```
materials_Cmb.dataProvider = 
    new XMLListCollection(xml_val.recommendedMaterials.children());
```

This should already do the trick. Note that I wrapped the XMLList in an XMLListCollection: this is not strictly necessary with the mx:ComboBox, because it will do the same internally, but for Spark components it would be mandatory.

Another more concise solution would be to just find all the 'value' nodes, but I don't know whether that approach fits your bill.

```
materials_Cmb.dataProvider = 
    new XMLListCollection(xml_val..value);
```

Also don't forget to assign the correct 'labelField' in the ComboBox:

```
<s:ComboBox labelField="@label" />
```

The @ sign represents an XML attribute.

Comment: ok.. thnx a lot!
However i was already confused between XML and XMLList, and you added a new one XMLListCollection. :(.  Added the term to my research :)

Comment: @VishwasGagrani Just to get you started: XML and XMLList are low-level ActionScript/E4X classes (E4X being the XML parsing idiom), whereas XMLListCollection is a class from the Flex framework. Basically XMLListCollection is to XMLList what ArrayCollection is to Array.